# Formatting time difference as `mm:ss` with date fns

Tags: javascript, date-formatting, date-fns

I'm currently using https://date-fns.org/v2.21.1/docs/differenceInSeconds to format distance between 2 dates in seconds, but if such distance is greater than 1min, various results come up like `67` seconds.

To make it more user friendly, I'd like to format this distance as `mm:ss` so

`00:59`
`01:00`
`02:34`

And so on. Currently closest I got to is using `differenceInSeconds` and `differenceInMinutes` and just concatenating 2 into a string like `${differenceInMinutes}:${differenceInSeconds}` issue is, that for 2 minutes I get result like `02:120`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the modulo (`%`) operator, it returns the remainder of division.
I've also used the `padStart` function to have the leading zeros displayed in the final string.

As the argument you just need to use the difference in seconds,

Here's a code snippet:

```js
function formatTime(time) {
  // Remainder of division by 60
  var seconds = time % 60;
  // Divide by 60 and floor the result (get the nearest lower integer)
  var minutes = Math.floor(time / 60); 

  // Put it all in one string
  return ("" + minutes).padStart(2, "0") + ":" + ("" + seconds).padStart(2, "0");
}

console.log(formatTime(15))
console.log(formatTime(65))
console.log(formatTime(123))
```